# Models imported from Blender to Unity are not the same

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

When I import a model to Unity I have missing faces. I tried to flip faces in Blender, the backface culling option... nothing does not work. Maybe I did something wrong? I can't tell.

I was wondering if it was a unity version problem. It is 2019.3.14f1 and Blender is latest, but I guess not; most of the faces are rendered.

Comment: The title `Models imported from Blender to Unity are the same` does not really match your description ;)

Answer (score 0):

After activating the normals, you need to make sure that the normals in the model are facing outward. If all your normals are in the right direction, you shouldn't run into any problems in Unity.
[Normals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8PGD.jpg)