# How is force applied to multiple objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a waterful ring toss game, but I have difficulty applying power from one point to all objects in the game.
Basically, what I want to do is to add force to all objects located between x and y points to move by applying force according to their positions.

I've been doing research on Unity forums, Stackoverflow, and Unity documents for a while, but I haven't been able to find what should ı do or use.
I'm looking for resources or suggestions to help me solve this problem. I apologize in advance if I asked the wrong question. This is my first question on this platform.

Here is an example screen:
[image: Example Screen]

The solution I found thanks to the comments:

```
            if (buttonPushed == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ringObject.Count; i++)
            {
                ringObject[i].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForceAtPosition(Vector3.up * force, transform.position);
                buttonPushed = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: See if [this](https://github.com/kleberandrade/attraction-repulsion-force-unity) helps you. You can filter the objects on which you want to apply the force by setting a bool in a code to specify that.

Comment: Isn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65767795/models-imported-from-blender-to-unity-are-not-the-same/65791096#65791096) your first question? ;)

Comment: Maybe use [`AddForceAtPosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition.html)

Comment: I think that was my first answer. This is my first question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way

You put your objects in a list and iterate over them and do whatever you want to do in a if statement in that loop.

Harder way.
Create an object in that area with a collider and get callbacks when your object collide with that big collider object.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Thanks to your suggestion, I managed to fix the problem. I added the code snippet above.